# Add action to dropdown depend on the items selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I've the next dropdown:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
 Seleccionar <span class="caret"></span>
</button>

<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" >
    <li><a href="#" id="domicilio" data-value="acasa-viajar">A domicilio / En mi lugar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="domicilio1" data-value="viajar">Sólo a domicilio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="noDomicilio" data-value="acasa">Sólo en mi lugar</a></li>
</ul>
```

And I need that when I select the Option A domicilio / En mi lugar or Sólo a domicilio it execute this action:

```
$("#provincias").removeClass('collapse');
```

I resolved it, but I'm sure this code isn't very well.

```
$('#domicilio').click(function(e) {
    $("#provincias").removeClass('collapse');
    e.preventDefault();// prevent the default anchor functionality
});

$('#domicilio1').click(function(e) {
    $("#provincias").removeClass('collapse');
    e.preventDefault();// prevent the default anchor functionality
});

$('#noDomicilio').click(function(e) {
    $("#provincias").addClass('collapse');
    e.preventDefault();// prevent the default anchor functionality
});
```

Thank you

Comment: please add missing tags (this is a jQuery question, right?) and specify more exactly what you are asking. Ah... and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work to encapsulate it in a single function (you might also want to add an ID to the select statement if you have more than one with the given class):

```
$('.dropdown-menu li a').on('click',function(){
    switch($(this).attr('id')){
        case 'domicilio':
            //execute your code;
            $('#provincias').removeClass('collapse');
            break;
        case 'domicilio1':
            //execute your code;
            $('#provincias').removeClass('collapse');
            break;
        case 'noDomicilio':
            //execute your code;
            $('#provincias').addClass('collapse');
            break;
    }
    e.preventDefaults();
});
```

Edited to reflect UL not SELECT

Comment: It's an ul, no select-tag. I guess this won't work. EDIT: But I'd prefer your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the a-tags.

```
$('.foo').on('click', function(e) {
    if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'noDomicilio' )
        $('#provincias').addClass('collapse');
    else 
        $('#provincias').removeClass('collapse');

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to **Add/Remove** Class and no Need to Change your **HTML**

```
$('.dropdown-menu li a').on('click', function(e) {
    if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'noDomicilio' )
        $('#provincias').addClass('collapse');
    else 
        $('#provincias').removeClass('collapse');

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/vf5tD/)</kbd>